# jQuery resize and viewport checkpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

I have a small problem with my script.

I want to change body background colour based on width of screen. My problem is I don't know that I have to change to make it work from under 960 to 1130.

Ex: Let's say I rezise my browser.

```
1300px -> 1150px = ok
1150px -> 1300px = ok
1150px -> 925px = ok
925px -> 1150px = **not ok** 

jQuery script:

$(window).resize(function() {
    viewportWidth = $(this).width();
    if ( viewportWidth >= 1200 && w < 1200){

        $('body').css('background', 'red');

        w = viewportWidth;

        console.log(w);

    }else if (viewportWidth < 1200 && w >= 1200) {

        $('body').css('background', 'green');

        w = viewportWidth;

        console.log(w);

    }else if (viewportWidth < 960 && w >= 960) {

        $('body').css('background', 'blue');

        w = viewportWidth;

        console.log(w);

    };
}).resize();
```

JsFiddle:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n4mxz9d/)

Comment: Is your question basically how to prevent resizing from 960 to 1130 going in that direction only, such that hitting the 1130 breakpoint and going down to 960 is okay, but at 960 and lower it is not okay to activate some logic until you once again get up to 1130? These numbers are inconsistent with comments in your code.

Comment: What I want is when I'm under 960 and the background is blue and I resize over 960 I want the background to be back to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is: When you are under 960, you are passing the window's size to the variable `w`. When you resize over 960, you are checking if the `(viewportWidth < 1200 && w >= 1200)` and, of course, the `w` is less than 1200, as you were in a smaller resolution.

Why are you using that variable anyway?
I suggest just remove it and do it in this way.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    viewportWidth = $(this).width();

    if ( viewportWidth < 960) {
        $('body').css('background', 'blue');
    } else if (viewportWidth < 1200) {
        $('body').css('background', 'green');
    } else {
        $('body').css('background', 'red');
    };
});
```

**EDIT:**

As you are using this variable to control your functions, you can still use it, just changing the middle if, like that:

```
var w = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(this).width();

    if (viewportWidth < 960 && w >= 960) {
        $('body').css('background', 'blue');
    } else if (viewportWidth < 1200 && (w < 960 || w >= 1200)) {
        $('body').css('background', 'green');
    } else if (viewportWidth >= 1200 && w < 1200) {
        $('body').css('background', 'red');
    };

    w = viewportWidth;
});
```

In this way, you will be able to avoid calling your functions in each resize.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using it to reinitialize some sliders. The background is just an example.

Comment: But have you tried this solution? You don't need to use this variable in the conditionals.

Comment: Ok ... I will mark your answer as ok because it will work on my question. I tried to use 'checkpoints' because I didn't want to reinitialize my functions everytime a user resizes the screen. I resolved that problem with a simple setTimeout and no it should be ok.

Comment: I think I understood your problem now. Check my update, I think it might help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If its just for changing the body color you're better off realizing this through pure CSS with the help of media queries.

See this [simple example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYBNab). The only thing you need are 2 media queries:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Javascript resize events are a bit trickier. When writing code for those, you should also consider following best practice for better perfomance:
[Leaner, Meaner, Faster Animations with requestAnimationFrame](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/).

Comment: Sorry ... It is not only for changing to body colour. I want to do js inside.